# Whenever i run this bit it always says that it failed to register. I dont know where im going wrong

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

This is the part where I try to update data using the unique user id. But it always shows fails to register, even though the authentication part is working.

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
     .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            if (task.isSuccessful())
            {
                user user=new user(
                nameOfUser,
                email,
                phNo
                );
                //Toast.makeText(Register_User.this, "Working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                mData.getReference("Users")
                        .child(Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid())
                        .push().setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        Toast.makeText(Register_User.this, "Upto here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(Register_User.this, "Successfully Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(Register_User.this, "Failed to Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are already registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the task failed, it has an exception that shows you the problem. You're currently not using that in any way, while it may point you to the solution:

```
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
    Toast.makeText(Register_User.this, "Successfully Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    Log.w(TAG, "Registering user failed", task.getException());
    Toast.makeText(Register_User.this, "Failed to Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Also see [create a password based account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account), in the Firebase documentation.

Comment: hi.. Thanks it worked. It came up with a daabase exception of: "Firebase Database error: Permission denied" i had changed the permissions. Thanks